# Get answer using a formula in python with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have some data like below, about a 100k rows with different batches.

```
batch    b       c
 A      10       2     
 A      20       4     
 A      30       6     
 B      5        1     
 B      10       2   
 B      15       3   
 B      20       4    
 .       .       .     
 .       .       . 
 .       .       .
```

What I am trying to do is to is, using a formula, I want only 1 line of data frame per group with the help of a summation formula.

The formula is same throughout all batches as below

```
           (b1xc1)+(b2xc2)+(b3xc3)   10x2 + 20x4 + 30x6    20 + 80 + 180     280
 batch A = _______________________ = __________________ = _______________ = _____ = 23.33
               c1 + c2 + c3             2 + 4 + 6              12            12
```

So the new_df will be:

```
batch   new_value
 A        23.3 
 B        15.0
 .         .
 .         .
 .         .
```

Please Note: there are zero values in col C, so might be possible divide by zero may occur.

With my approach I created a new column bxc and then summing up values by group and dividing by sum of c for that group, but I think it is not much effective way. Is there an alternate way to achieve this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier to follow I am recreating sample `data` as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'batch': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'b': [10, 20, 30, 5, 10, 15, 20],
        'c': [2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then I would recommend using a custom function to calculate the value and to avoid division by zero:

```py
def calculate_new_value(group):
    numerator = (group['b'] * group['c']).sum()
    denominator = group['c'].sum()
    
    if denominator == 0:
        return 0
    
    return round(numerator / denominator, 1)
```

Applying this function with `apply`  after `groupby` and setting your index with `reset_index` to `new_value` results in:

```py
print(df.groupby('batch').apply(calculate_new_value).reset_index(name='new_value'))

  batch  new_value
0     A  23.3
1     B  15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The following appears to be fast enough. Although the idea is similar to @mozway's one, it appears to be faster (maybe because mine does not use `eval`).

```
out = df.assign(bc = df['b'].mul(df['c'])).groupby('batch').sum()
out = out['bc'].div(out['c']).reset_index(name='new_value')
```

Output:

```
  batch  new_value
0     A  23.333333
1     B  15.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient is to pre-compute the product, then use sums:

```
(df.eval('p = b*c')
   .groupby('batch')[['c', 'p']].sum()
   .eval('p / c')
   .reset_index(name='new_value')
)
```

Or with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('batch').apply(lambda g: g['c'].mul(g['b']).sum() / g['c'].sum())
         .reset_index(name='new_value')
       )
```

Output:

```
  batch  new_value
0     A  23.333333
1     B  15.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('batch').apply(lambda x:x['b'].dot(x['c'])/x['c'].sum())
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**